# Can I edit Asp.net Mvc cshtml after publish?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to edit the .cshtml files after publish or are there any draw backs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can edit the .cshtml file after you publish it.

Yes, there are drawbacks.

- If you edit on the production server, you are bypassing QA
- You are not going through a proper build cycle
- You must integrate this change into version control

I strongly recommend adhering to a cycle

- Code
- Unit test
- Check in
- Publish / Deploy to QA
- Test in QA
- Go back to "Code" as needed
- Publish / Deploy to PROD
- If something breaks, go back to "Code"

Use a version control system that supports branching and tagging to make that cycle much easier.

Even if "QA" is a VM on your development server and you put on the "QA" hat, I would not skip that step.

Comment: But not if you [compile before runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482007/how-to-compile-cshtml-before-runtime), correct?

Comment: Drawbacks aside, how would you do this?