# How to compile cshtml before runtime

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, razor

I believe I read somewhere there is a setting in one of the project files that will allow you to compile the `.cshtml` files when building your Visual Studio project.

Just getting started with `MVC/Razor/Query` Mobile, and am getting annoyed with the "Error loading page" when I have an error in a code block inside a `.cshtml` file

Comment: http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compile Views in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383192/compile-views-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Set `<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>` in the `<PropertyGroup>` element of your .csproj file.

Comment: any place to set this within the UI?

Comment: Within the UI of Visual Studio? Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: This works, but I noticed it causes a different compiler error, so I had to turn it back off.

Comment: Are you sure that your compiler error isn't linked to a view compilation problem? Last time I used this feature, when my views didn't compile I got strange compilation error messages...

Comment: actually, this is the problem I had: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725387/mvcbuildviews-not-working-correctly

Comment: MvcBuildViews is often mistakenly, as it doesn’t precompile views as you image. See my answer for details (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53319065/752004)

Answer (score 16):

Besides the true setting, you still need to ensure below setting is active in your csproj:

```
<Target Name="MvcBuildViews" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
<AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(WebProjectOutputDir)" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Error **Failed to map the path '/**' and **Failed to map the path 'temp'**  what is the reason?

Answer (score 6):

**MvcBuildViews is often mistakenly**, as it doesn’t precompile views in the terms you'd like.

MvcBuildViews builds views temporarily and gives build results back to building process to show possible build error in VS errors window.

For achieving a real precompilation of views for production release, you have to properly set specific values in the *Publish Web App* configuration window of your project.

See [here](https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet/asp-net-mvc-precompiling-views/) for the main article about how to do it via Visual Studio and [here](http://blog.deltacode.be/2017/01/08/fix-slow-startup-of-asp-net-mvc-5-on-azure-app-services/) for going deeper on how to do it via msBuild and Azure.

#### UPDATE

In a nutshell, with Visual Studio you have to configure the Publish window as:

[image: Main publish window]

and

[image: Advanced configuration window]

Answer (score 0):

Whether if any errors inside a script part in cshtmls can be spotted at build time. Because , when used MvcBuildViews to be true. It compiles alone cshtml but not that script part errors.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).