# Precompile ASP.NET Web Pages razor (*.cshtml) files

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-webpages

For an MVC project, there is the `<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>` property that can be set in the csproj file, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482007/how-to-compile-cshtml-before-runtime). However, that has no effect in my Web Pages kind of project. Is there a similar switch that I could use?

Note: Typical Web Pages project is of type "Web Site", i.e. no csproj. My solution, however, uses Web Pages inside a normal Web Application project so I have csproj, it all compiles fine, runs fine, I just don't have any compile-time checking of my `*.cshtml` files which I'd like to add.

Comment: I answered pretty much this exact question yesterday. [VS2013 does not compile ASP.NET MVC5 views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28289107/vs2013-does-not-compile-asp-net-mvc5-views)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at the [RazorGenerator](https://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/) for implementing the soultion you want. I am not sure if it will work with a Web Site project