# Visual Studio displaying errors even if projects build successfully in Razor html

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Intellisense not working for any razor html tags. Also showing Red line in all razor html tags `(@Html.TexBox, @Html.DropdownList MultiSelect etc)`

Three types error are showing in Visual Studio Error Window.

**Error #1:**

> The type arguments for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBoxFor(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary)' cannot be
>   inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

**Error #2:**

> One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be
>   found. Are you missing references to Microsoft.CSharp.dll and
>   System.Core.dll?

**Error #3:**

> Error 40  The type arguments for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.HiddenFor(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

Please see the attached link for more information.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Show us your code. We don't know what you did wrong if you don't show us what you did.

Comment: I've seen Intellisense get out of sync for Razor files. Usually closing and opening VS fixed it. Have you tried that? Also, it seems by default if there's an error in your view, it doesn't fail the build, so you have to manually notice these compilation issues. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28346348/1139830) for a resolution on that.

Comment: Please see the the link [link](http://s10.postimg.org/4h9ukt6y1/error.jpg)
[link](http://s24.postimg.org/novf33kid/error.jpg)

Comment: I generally would restart VS, clean solution and finally rebuild.

Comment: still problem persist

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Problem solved deleted all the contents from the following folder.

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files

Thank you all for your time. :)

Comment: No change at all with this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have following section in your web.config (Root should be fine)

```
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            </assemblies>
       </compilation>
    </system.web>
```

Replace System.Web.Helpers version as per your reference.

Comment: I had a similar problem with System.Linq (part of System.Core assembly).  Finally after hours of searching, this was the solution that worked.  @Anil, much appreciation.

Answer (score 0):

That happens to me from time to time, usually rebuilding the project which contains the errors works for me. Did you try that?

Let me know.

Comment: still problem persist

Comment: Try adding another view, copying the content, and then deleting the old one.

Answer (score 0):

If the close and rebuild doesn't sort it I suspect there is an issue with your project file.

Create a new ASP.net web app and copy your files over.  A bit of a pain but it will probably work.

Comment: cant do it . Working in TFS

Comment: Give it a go and see if it works, if it does you could probably look at the differences between the two project files and manually update the one you have in TFS.  Has it always done it?

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me also, apparently the intellisense stoped working so everything in the razor views was shown as an error, but the project compiled fine and even the views weren't throwing errors.

Googling I found this page: https://lostindetails.com/articles/fixing-razor-intellisense

That's what worked for me, deleting the cache folder in this location:
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache

changing the 14.0 for the appropiate Visual Studio version.

Credits to the guy that wrote that website.