# Prevention or Details of Razor error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the code below, which works fine. Suppose I now want to change something in the `ActionLinkButton` method, like add another
parameter to its signature. I would then have to change the call in .cshtml as well, of course. However, there is no compile error if I don't change the 
.cshtml, the application just crashes when attempting to display the `View`, getting directed to the default error html page.There is no detail of the error in the logs, in firebug, anywhere.
Obviously, I should try to remember to check all calls when I make such a change, but I forget.
So, how can I prevent this error or make it easier to trace?
1. Some sort of Razor syntax checker?
2. Some way of directing to an error page with some meaningful message?

.cs

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLinkButton(
         this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
         string buttonText,
         string actionName,
         string controllerName,
         RouteValueDictionary routeValues,
         Boolean enable) 
     {
         string href = UrlHelper.GenerateUrl("default", actionName, controllerName, routeValues, RouteTable.Routes, htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext, false);
         // title is tooltip
         string buttonHtml;
         if (enable)
         {
             buttonHtml = string.Format("<input type=\"button\"  title=\"Export\" value=\"{0}\" onclick=\"location.href='{1}'\" class=\"button\" />", buttonText, href);
         }
         else // disable button
         {
             buttonHtml = string.Format("<input type=\"button\"  disabled=\"disabled\" title=\"Export\" value=\"{0}\" onclick=\"location.href='{1}'\" class=\"button\" />", buttonText, href);
         }
             return new MvcHtmlString(buttonHtml);
}
```

.cshtml

```
@Html.ActionLinkButton(
             buttonText: "Export",
             actionName: "Export",
             controllerName: "Detail",
             routeValues: new RouteValueDictionary(new {PermitId = @Model.PermitId }),
             enable : false)
```

Comment: have you debug your code, verify the parameters of method its maybe  here the error.

Comment: Edit the Web.config file to turn off customErrors mode.

Comment: Yes, this does give accurate information. Thanks. I had had the Web.Debug.config file set this to off, but this was insufficient. I had to do it in Web.config.

Comment: Some third party tools (`Resharper` and `Just Code` from Telerik) validate cshtml files tool. There is also an option in Visual Studio to turn on pre-compiling of views which will probably help you more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compile your Razor views at build time so you will get razor compile error before run.

> Set `<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>` in the `<PropertyGroup>` element of your .csproj file.

[How to compile cshtml before runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482007/how-to-compile-cshtml-before-runtime)

This can be slow, I enable it only in release.

Comment: This causes build error: 
Error 3 
It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  
This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Comment: Fix is to do as Chris Hynes suggests here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725387/mvcbuildviews-not-working-correctly